# How can I have multiple filters on my data in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, javascript-objects

I am having trouble having multiple filters on my list of data in react. Currently I have one filter working which is only returning the list item if the city of the data matches the filter city, but how can I simultaneously filter the price, city, and also search all together ?

here is my component

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react'
            import ListingStreamItem from './ListingStreamItem'
            import zipcodes from 'zipcodes'
            class Home extends Component {
                constructor(props) {
                    super(props)
                    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
                    this.state = {
                        visitor_city: '',

                    }
                }
                componentDidMount() { 
                    const _this = this;
                    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
                        console.log(response.city, response.country);
                        _this.setState({
                            visitor_city: response.city
                        })
                    }, "jsonp");

                }
                handleChange(e) {
                    this.setState({
                        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
                    })
                }
                render(){

                    const user = this.props.user !== null ? true : false
                    const listings = this.props.listings == null ? 'There are no listings available at this time' : Object.keys(this.props.listings).reverse().map((key) => {
                        var areEqual = this.state.visitor_city.toUpperCase() === this.props.listings[key].city.toUpperCase();

                        if (areEqual) {
                            return (
                                <li key={key}>
                                    <ListingStreamItem 
                                        id={key}
                                        title={this.props.listings[key].title}
                                        desc={this.props.listings[key].description}
                                        price={this.props.listings[key].price}
                                        zipcode={this.props.listings[key].zipcode}
                                        images={this.props.listings[key].listingimages}
                                    />
                                </li>
                            )
                        }
                    }) 
                    return(
                        <div>

                        <select name="visitor_city" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <option value="orlando">Orlando </option>
                            <option value="new york city">New York City</option>
                        </select>
                        <p>Or Zip Code </p>
                        <input type='number' min="0" name='miles_from_zip' placeholder="miles" value={this.state.miles_from_zip} />
                        <input type='text' name="zipcode" placeholder="from zip" value={this.state.zipcode} />
                        <button>Filter </button>
                        <ul>
                            {listings}
                        </ul>

                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }

            export default Home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just do another if inside your map (this is the simple solution assuming your price filter is also in state):

```
const listings = this.props.listings == null ? 'There are no listings available at this time' : Object.keys(this.props.listings).reverse().map(key => {
    let {visitor_city, price} = this.state;
    let listing = this.props.listings[key];

    if (visitor_city.toUpperCase() === listing.city.toUpperCase()
        && (!price || price === listing.price)
    ) {
        return (
        ...
        )
    }
})
```

---

A cleaner option might be to look at the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijlI-Iw5PWAhVGI1AKHcoGDUUQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHTybPLK3GeAl_0DVx-FLbAD2mWtw) function:

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
var words = ["spray", "limit", "elite", "exuberant", "destruction", "present"];

var longWords = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);

// Filtered array longWords is ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

---

So in your scenario perhaps you could do something like:

```
Object.keys(this.props.listings).reverse().filter(key => {
    let {visitor_city, price} = this.state;
    let listing = this.props.listings[key];

    return visitor_city.toUpperCase() === listing.city.toUpperCase()
        && (!price || price === listing.price)    
}).map(key => {
    ...
})
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much!! I attempted to use filter before asking this question but since I was trying to figure how to get that working with the object.key method in place.